# XPath : Number of Occurrence of an element

Tags: xpath

How do i get the output for first tag starting with `"<intro><longtitle"` as 1 . Second tag `"<intro><longtitle>"` as 2 and so on using XPATH.  The need is to get the occurrence of the element .

```
<intro><longtitle> Demo </longtitle>
..
..

<intro><longtitle> Test </longtitle>
.
.
<intro><longtitle> Demo Test</longtitle>
```

Regards,
Sri

Comment: It's not clear what you mean "as 1" and "as 2". If you're trying to reference the various longtitles by their numeric index, you could use `(//intro/longtitle)[2]`, where `2` is the index you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

For your XML corrected to be well-formed,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<r> 
  <intro>
    <longtitle> Demo </longtitle>
  </intro>  
  <intro>
    <longtitle> Test </longtitle>
  </intro>  
  <intro>
    <longtitle> Demo Test </longtitle>
  </intro> 
</r>
```

you can specify the `intro` element with a `Test` string value of `longtitle`:

```
//intro[normalize-space(longtitle) = 'Test']
```

and count the preceding siblings,

```
count(//intro[normalize-space(longtitle) = 'Test']/preceding-sibling::intro) + 1
```

to determine that the selected `intro` is the second sibling:

```
2
```

Comment: In my case the "Test" or  long-title value will not be exposed.                                               Is there a way to get output as  '1' if i use XPath from <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<r> 
  <intro>
    <longtitle> Demo </longtitle>
  </intro>

Comment: You can output it as `1` rather than `2` by removing the `+1`, but I'm not sure what you mean when you say that "Test" would not be exposed.  Are you saying that you cannot test against the string "Test"?   If so, how is it that you will specify the criteria of the `intro` for which you wish to know the number of its occurrence?

Comment: In my case the "Test" or  long-title value will not be exposed.                                               Is there a way to get output as  '1' if i use XPath from first longtitle tag and "2" as sencond long-title and so on .

Comment: Your request as stated is too circular to make sense:  You want '1' for first and '2' for second `longtitle`?  If you select based on an index, there's no reason to then return an index.

Comment: sto be more precise , these tags wont be one below the another . They are scattered in a bug junk xml.I am planning to create a variable "x" that will hold the value 1 for the first tag ,2 for second occuring tag and so on... This X value will be my Chapter page. (a dynamic approach )

Comment: core logic like ,                                                                                                 start        = 0

total titles = 3


[if((start + 1) < total titles) {
return start + 1
}else{
return 3;}]

Comment: You can use `preceding::intro` rather than `preceding-sibling::intro` to count `intro` elements earlier in the document rather than only earlier siblings.  If this doesn't help, I'm afraid I have no idea what you're trying to do.   Good luck.